# R: Dataframe: error arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r

I am currently tring to stitch all this into a single object using this code:

```
GEDF <- data.frame(LTG,GEPVals,GELogFoldChanges,GEAdjPVals,GEThreshold);
```

But this error appears:

```
Error in data.frame(LTG, GEPVals, GELogFoldChanges, GEAdjPVals, GEThreshold) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1299, 18382, 18383
```

What does this mean and how do I correct it? I have 18383 genes in columns and 1299 rows

| primary.disease | study | A1BG | TOP2A | A2M | CCNB1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LUAD | TCGA | 6.4 | 8.9 | 2.3 | 7.9 |
| LUAD | TCGA | 7.8 | 7.9 | 1.0 | 9.3 |
| LUAD | TCGA | 8.0 | 8.8 | 0.6 | 9.2 |
| LUSC | TCGA | 6.9 | 6.7 | 0 | 8.5 |
| LUNG | GTEX | 7.1 | 2.1 | 5.5 | 1.1 |
| LUNG | GTEX | 7.4 | 1.3 | 4.8 | 4.6 |

My original dataset table has 1299 rows, 18390 columns and 18383 genes.
i want to find the expression level of genes in tumour(TCGA) vs normal (GTEX) and then plot this as a volcano plot using ggplot2.

I've adapted the code that i used orginally to cater to the example table i provided. i wanted to find the p value for all columns using the apply function so i did something similar to this:

```r
GEPVals <- apply(LTG[-2],2,function(x) t.test(x[1:4],x[5:6])$p.value)
```

but this error appeared:
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :

missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In var(y) :

so then i applied this code instead:

```r
GEPVals <- apply(LTG[-2],2,function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

and then applied this code to adjust my p values using FDR:

```r
GEAdjPVals <- p.adjust(GEPVals, method="fdr")
```

and then this code to find the log fold changes for all the genes:

```r
GELogFoldChanges <- apply(TCGA_GTEX_lung[-7], 2, function(x) log(sum(x[1:4]/sum(x[5:6])))
```

this gave me an error like: Error in sum(x[1:4]) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
so i did:

```r
GELogFolds <- apply(LTG,2,function(x) log(sum(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))[1:4]/sum(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))[5:6], na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Then did the following...
library(ggplot2)

```r
LogTwoFold <- log(2)
```

Create a vector of judgments; does each gene pass p-value and fold change requirements:

```r
    GEThreshold <- abs(GELogFoldChanges)>LogTwoFold & GEAdjPVals < 0.05 
;:
```

and this is where I'm at, stitching all the information into a single object:

```r
   GEDF <- data.frame(GeneExp,GEPVals,GELogFoldChanges,GEAdjPVals,GEThreshold);
```

i plan to apply this code after:

```r
g <- ggplot(data=GEDF,
    aes(x=GELogFoldChanges, y=-log(GEAdjPVals), color=GEThreshold))+
    geom_point()+
    theme(legend.position="none")+
    xlab("log fold changes")+
    ylab("negative log p-value")`
```

Add a horizontal line to show threshold p-value,
and add two vertical lines to show threshold fold changes using:

```r
g + geom_hline(yintercept=-log(0.05)) + geom_vline(xintercept=LogTwoFold) + geom_vline(xintercept=log(1/2))
```

Comment: As the error says, how to put together columns which don't have the same length so that the rows correspond?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding. I'm confused sorry. So i have 18383 columns and 1299 rows in my dataset, All the columns are the same length in my table. So i don't understand why error says they're differing?

Comment: What is the result of `nrow(LTG);nrow(GEPVals);nrow(GELogFoldChanges);nrow(GEAdjPVals);nrow(GEThreshold)` ?

Comment: I ran the code you gave me and i got this: [1] 1299
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

Comment: `nrow(object)` returns `NULL`if the object doesn't exist. So only `LTG` seems to exist in your current environment. What is the result of `exists('GEPVals')`?

Comment: i ran exists('GEPVals') and it said TRUE.

Comment: OK, then `nrow(GEPVals)` shouldn't return `NULL`

Comment: How do you think i should i correct this error?

Comment: OK, understood, some are vectors, others data.frames : try `length(GEPVals)` instead on nrow(), same for the others.

Comment: i ran the code you gave for each and LTG, GELogFoldChanges and GEThreshold came with the number 18383 wheras GEPVals and GEAdjPVals came back with 18382?

Comment: This is the problem you can read in the error message : data.frame is expecting vectors of  identical length.

Comment: Ahh i don't understand why that has happened I am very confused why they are not identical. I am new to R so I'm not really sure if i made an error in these codes that may be the reason why my vectors are not same in length? Here is my code i wrote to find the p value for all columns: GEPVals <- apply(LTG[-7],2,function(x) length(unique(x))) and my code for finding log fold change for all columns: GELogFolds <- apply(LTG,2,function(x) log(sum(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))[1:1011]/sum(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))[1012:1299], na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE))). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you edit your question with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi Waldo! I have given an example similar to my dataset and also tried to provide code similar to what i've done so you can see what i've been trying to do and where i've been going wrong and how i should correct it so i can create my plot.